# Hibernate jar files in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, jar

I'm new to hibernate and eclipse and tried to code "hello world" program by using the [tutorial](http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/hibernate-hello-world-program-in-eclipse/)

Also i'm using hibernate 4.1.8 version. When i tried to run the program the first error is "The import org.hibernate cannot be resolved" .Searched about it and i got i'm missing jar files. These jar files are in .rar format in my downloaded 4.1.8 hibernate. when i extract i cant find a .jar file. where can i find .jar file after extraction?

Comment: Have you added the jars to your classpath?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? If so an easy google produced this: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-%28Java%29

Answer (score 1):

You can download jars from hibernate official site : http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/

After downloading jars; pls put them in your **CLASSPATH** so that your code in eclipse can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Download hibernate Jar's from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate4/4.1.8.Final/).

After downloading the zip extract it and copy jar's inside `hibernate-release-4.1.8.Final/lib` to your `classpath`.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Write URL https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/ in browser.

Step 2) Click on the **"More info"** button attached with the latest version.

Step 3) Click on the **"Download Zip archive"** button on the right side.

Step 4) Hence Hibernate JAR files are downloaded successfully.

Step 5) Extract the downloaded zip file.

Step 6) Click on the extracted file.

Step 7) Click on the **lib** folder.

Step 8) Click on the **required** folder.

Step 9) Select all the files using keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+A** & **Copy** all files.

Step 10) Paste the copied files in **"WebContent/Web-INF/lib"** folder in eclipse.

Step 11) For **database connection** , follow **hibernate-release-5.5.9.Final\lib\optional\c3p0** path in your PC and copy all the JAR files.

Step 12) Paste the copied files in **"WebContent/Web-INF/lib"** folder in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the latest jars from http://www.hibernate.org/downloads

Add those jars tour classpath and Happy ORM persistence !!!

Answer (score -1):

**Right click on your project ->  properties -> Build path -> config build Path -> choose Librey.**

in right side corner you saw a content Add External jarfile select it.
then **copy all the jar file** which you want.
then come to your project and paste it.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your project web-inf then you will get lib folder. Copy all your hibernate and jdbc file and paste there simply.

Comment: Your suggestion was already made 4 years ago in a better format.